# How to set correctly two types of user and firewalls on Symfony security?

Tags: symfony, security, firewall

I'm new to symfony and it is getting really hard to understand the documentation about security. So I'm here in hope that someone can lend me a hand. I've been working on teachers(profesores) and students(alumnos), where each of then can just access to their respective area (/profesores/.* and /alumnos/.*). However, I get the browser login to appear when I access these url, but they don't get the created users from their respective entities.

My security is set as follows:
security:

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    area_profesores:
        pattern: /profesores/.*
        provider: profesores_desde_bd
        switch_user:
                role: ROLE_PROFESOR
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /profesores/login_check
            login_path: /profesores/login
        logout:
            path: /profesores/logout
            target: /portada/

    area_alumnos:
        pattern: /alumnos/.*
        provider: alumnos_desde_bd
        switch_user:
                role: ROLE_ALUMNO
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /alumnos/login_check
            login_path: /alumnos/login
        logout:
            path: /alumnos/logout
            target: /portada/


    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/profesores, roles: ROLE_PROFESOR}
    - { path: ^/alumnos, roles: ROLE_ALUMNO }
    - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    profesores_desde_bd:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\Profesores
            property: username
    alumnos_desde_bd:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\Alumnos
            property: username


encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\Profesores:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
        iterations: 0
    AppBundle\Entity\Alumnos:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
        iterations: 0

    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        #http_basic: ~

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        #form_login: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

I need to erase 
 main:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
since that authentication does not log me in.